# How to compare Lists of Integers in DB? Java

Tags: java, postgresql

We have entity:

```java
Class Drink {
Long id;
String name;
List "Integer" ingredients; // We store ingredient's numbers in this list
}
```

For example: id = 1, name = Mojito, ingredients = {5,7,3,8}

Let's say, i want to find a drink based on ingredients. How should I do that?

1. Retrieve all cocktails from data base and iterate through them for comparison?
2. Or comparison should be conducted in a data-base? If this is correct answer, How can I to that? (How to compare Lists of Integers in the DB)?

Comment: Hi!  Your code doesn't compile, so you may want to address that.  How is the ingredients list being persisted?  What persistence are you using?

Comment: You can do it both in DB and in code. How you should do it depends on your architecture, needs etc …. SO cannot really help you with this.

Comment: A question from a database viewpoint is why even store a list of integers, instead of storing a normalized number of records that match drinks to their ingredients? One example would be an `ingredients` table, `drinks` table, and a `drink_ingredients` junction table. Basically, you're using lists to store lists, and asking about functions for lists of lists, instead of just storing a list directly and using the operations available for that.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you'll want to filter the data on the database level. The exact solution depends on the type of the database structure and the framework that you use, but since you use PostgreSQL, I assume you have a relational database structure, and since you speak of an "entity", I assume you use something like Hibernate or JPA to interact with it.

Then probably your drinks should reference their ingredients not as numbers, but as entities. This is how the mapping could look like:

```java
class Drink {

    Long id;

    String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(tableName = "drink_ingredients")
    List<Ingredient> ingredients;
}

class Ingredient {

    Long id;

    String name;
}
```

Then a query to find all drinks containing a specific ingredient would be:

```java
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select d from Drink d " 
    + "join d.ingredients i "
    + "where i.name = :ingredientName");
query.setParameter("ingredientName", "Lime");
List<Drink> drinks = (List<Drink>) query.getResultList();
```